# multithreading for file load in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, zip

I need to zip each text file and copy into another server. File size may very from 500MB to 8GB. there is no dependency in each file. I have 35 files Appx.

My regular code taking appx 3-4 hours for this. To reduce the time, I am just thinking to implement Threading for this. Do you thing Threading will reduce the time or is there any other best way to do this.

Comment: First find out if it's taking a long time because you have to zip the files and it's using 100% of one core, or because the copy over the network is slow.

Comment: `File size may very from 500MB to 8GB` - a ZIP file cannot be larger than 4GB. How do you expect to zip an 8GB file?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov The minimum size of a zip file is 22 bytes.
The maximum size for both the archive file and the individual files inside it is 4,294,967,295 bytes (232−1 bytes, or 4 GiB) for standard ZIP, and 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 bytes (264−1 bytes, or 16 EiB) for ZIP64

Comment: Are you merging everything into a single file, or creating individual zip files?

Comment: It's almost impossible to answer this question "as is" because we don't know what part is taking 3-4 hours.  Doing it in parallel may cause the bottleneck to move, or may even cause failures if you try to jam too much across a slow connection.

Comment: Either measure what causes code to take so long or simply grab book/bear/game/movie and enjoy 4-5 hours of the process. Based on you description threading is not likely to help.

Comment: Is the zipping taking most the time or network transfer? That would be a start.

Comment: @Science_Fiction +1. It is more likely the network or Hard drive that is bottlenecking than the actual zipping of the file. Multithreading won't help much if any in this scenario.

Comment: OK first, give it a try.  Run two copies of your app copying 17/18 files to the other server, (eg. copy 17/18 from different source folders).  See how long it takes. If the time taken is significantly less then, yes, move to multiple threads for the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

.Net 4.0 has a new Threading.Task namespace that makes it a lot easier to schedule tasks without having to get deep into the threading scheduling.

It allows you to queue up subsequent tasks to run once the previous one has completed (regardless of success or failure).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx

http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks

But, as previous commenters have suggested, if the bottleneck isn't the CPU doing the file compression, but rather the network transfer then it may not help much.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` because it by default creates 1 thread per core and que ups the other thread.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience in working with large files, multi-threading does not speed up the process due to the limitations on the Hard Drive read/write itself and/or network.

You are not only doing a lot of reading and writing with your hard drive, but also copying large files to another computer over the network.

If your average file size is 4.25 GB, that comes out to be  148.75GB of storage space we are dealing with (at 35 file count). That is a lot of space and not only are you reading all that space into memory (hopefully not all at once, otherwise virtual memory will start kicking in and it will write out even more to your hard drive), you are also writing some of that space back out as a zip file.

Add that factor to file transfer over a network, I am not surprised at all at the times you are getting if your network is typical of the networks I have to deal with. Megabit and Gigabit speeds are never what they claim they are.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an external utility for zipping (i.e. 7-zip), and process spin up is not a concern for your application , I would keep it simple and just Process.Start() as many 7-zip EXEs as you need to do the tasks in (quasi) parallel, or do some number at a time, like 5. Up to you.